# Javascript How to store and return responses from multiple async API calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have the following function that calls an API several times:

```
function define(arr, callback) {
    var client = [];
    var definitions = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            client[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (client[i].readyState == 4 && client[i].status == 200) {
                    definitions[arr[i]] = client[i].responseText;
                }
            };
            client[i].open('GET', 'http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/' + arr[i] +
                '/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=false&sourceDictionaries=webster&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=...',
                true);
            client[i].send();
        })(i);
    }
    return definitions;
}
```

As explained in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) the `return` occurs before the async calls finish causing the function to return an empty object.

Because I have a loop executing many calls I cannot use the solution of `status == 200` with a callback that returns what I want.

Things I've tried include making a global variable object and a callback that appends new key value pair to it every time it is called. This doesn't work for the same reason the original code doesn't.

I've also attempted to make a callback that returns the object and passing it to another function that doesn't make the call until a condition is met. This seems like the most promising path but I'm unsure of what condition I could use that would be true only after all async calls are finished as the callback would only have access to variables passed to it as arguments.

Comment: Have a look at Promises and `Promise.all`, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/925/waiting-for-multiple-concurrent-promises#t=201607281713298352612

Answer (score 0):

You could use fetch and promises for this. Ofc for older browsers you would have to use [some polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

```js
const urls = [
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fizyk20/generic-array/master/README.md',
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fizyk20/generic-array/master/src/iter.rs'
];

function getAll(urls) {
  const promises = urls.map(url => {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.text()); //or response.json() for json data and 
      //you can check response.ok property to see if response was successful
  });
  
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

getAll(urls)
  .then(txts => console.log(txts.slice(0, 400)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
You only have to check, each time a request finishes/a returned definition is stored in `definitions`, if the number of results in `definitions` equals the number of entries in the array `arr`.
If all results have been stored in `definitions` call the `callback` and pass it the `definitions`

```
client[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (client[i].readyState == 4 && client[i].status == 200) {
        definitions[arr[i]] = client[i].responseText;

        if (Object.keys(definitions).length === arr.length) {
            callback(definitions);
        }
    }
};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkd0z052/)

Comment: There is one problem with this, if ``client[i].readyState == 4 && client[i].status == 200`` ever one will be falsy, then callback will never be called. So there is need for failCallback or something like that.